# Serilog structured data doesn't work in Google Cloud functions with C# / .NET

Tags: function, google-cloud-platform, serilog, structured-data

We're using Serilog (wrapped in a .NET `ILogger`) to perform logging in Google Cloud functions written using .NET Core, and also in ASP.NET Core APIs that are in Kubernetes containers in Google Cloud.  When we try to add structured data to show up in Google's `jsonPayload` in each logged event, it works for the ASP.NET Core services, but doesn't work for the .NET Core functions.

Here is the code we're using.  The first three batches of code are how we initialize Serilog, separately for APIs and functions, plus their shared config dependency.  After those examples is how we add Serilog `LogContext` information that should appear in Google's `jsonPayload` for APIs and functions.  After those examples is the `appsettings.json` content for logging, which is pretty standard.

Short version of "what we're expecting" is for our arbitrary DTO to show up in `properties` after our `message` in `jsonPayload` when we look in Google Cloud Logs Explorer and examine any logging from the function.

Our thinking has focused on the fact that the APIs have different "host builder" objects than the .NET Core objects, even though both host builders implement `IHostBuilder`.  But that could easily be wrong.  Someone let us know!

And yes, we do have all the prescribed NuGet packages installed.

**Initialization code: APIs**

```cs
    public static WebApplicationBuilder AddStructuredLoggerToCloudApiService(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var definition = DefineLoggingSetup(builder.Configuration);
        var logger = definition.CreateLogger();

        builder.Host.ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddSerilog(logger));

        // Chainable.
        return builder;
    }
```

**Initialization code: functions**

```cs
    public static IHostBuilder AddStructuredLoggerToCloudFunction(this IHostBuilder builder, WebHostBuilderContext context)
    {
        var definition = DefineLoggingSetup(context.Configuration);
        var logger = definition.CreateLogger();

        builder.ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddSerilog(logger));

        // Chainable.
        return builder;
    }
```

**Initialization code: shared config dependency**

```cs
    private static LoggerConfiguration DefineLoggingSetup(IConfiguration config)
    {
        var definition = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)   // Scoped to calling code: sinks, message template.
            .Enrich.FromLogContext();         // Supports later AddLogData, etc.

        return definition;
    }
```

**Using `LogContext`**

```cs
    public static IDisposable AddLogData<TLogData>(this ILogger _, TLogData data)
    {
        return LogContext.PushProperty(typeof(TLogData).Name, data, true);
    }
```

**Logging config in `appsettings.json`**

```json
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.GoogleCloudLogging" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "GoogleCloudLogging",
        "Args": {
          "projectID": "************",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "outputTemplate": "****=> {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

(The exact GCP project ID has been redacted.)

Comment: Have you checked these [readme](https://github.com/manigandham/serilog-sinks-googlecloudlogging/blob/master/README.md) and [changelog](https://github.com/manigandham/serilog-sinks-googlecloudlogging/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) if these affect your setup?

Comment: Hi Robert G, thanks for your response.  Yes, I had checked out the read-me a few times.  I hadn't checked the change-log before.  From reading it now, it doesn't look like there is anything that settles the question for us.  There may well be a setup / GCP configuration issue at fault rather than the code, but nothing has made a difference after many Google searches and related attempts at fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this problem ever arises for anyone else, I'm posting the answer here, though I hate ending up having to answer my own questions in StackOverflow.

**Short answer:**  When you're using a Google Cloud function, you have to set up logging in an override of a different predefined method, `ConfigureLogging()`.  The builder in this method is an `ILoggingBuilder`, irregularly named `logging` by default, and the context here is a `WebHostBuilderContext`.

Our final code there looks like this:

```cs
logging.AddStructuredLoggerToCloudFunction(context);
```

The definition of `AddStructured___()` had to change slightly to use the `ILoggingBuilder`, but that was the only change.

That's all there is to it.